# Javascript 'if' statement using .includes()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing file paths as strings. I need to search through this array & make a new array including only those which contain a certain word. How would I create an if statement that includes the 'includes' method?

Here's my code so far:

```
var imagePaths = [...]

if(imagePaths.includes('index') === 'true'){
 ???
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to compare booleans to anything; just use them:

```
if (imagePaths.includes('index')) {
    // Yes, it's there
}
```

or

```
if (!imagePaths.includes('index')) {
    // No, it's not there
}
```

If you *do* decide to compare the boolean to something (which in general is poor practice), compare to `true` or `false`, not `'true'` (which is a string).

Answer (score 1):

**'true' != true**:

```
if (imagePaths.includes('index') === true) {
 ???
}
```

Or, which is way better, just use the value directly, since `if` already checks if the expression it receives is equal to true:

```
if (imagePaths.includes('index')) {
 ???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, to make a new array based on some condition, it's better to use `array.filter` method.

Ex:

```
var imagePaths = [...];

var filterImagePaths = imagePaths.filter(function(imagePath){

//return only those imagepath which fulfill the criteria

   return imagePath.includes('index');

});
```

Comment: No. The OP may use .some but i dont know how filtering relates to the question?

Comment: Filter will create a new array which satisfies the condition i.e., includes a specific word.